# Retrieve data using form from Dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query in Access named '*Laufzettel*' and it looks in this way. The dates are in dd.mm.yyyy format

```
Antragsnummer   Eingang    esigniert    Ausgang     Anlage    Policierung

   111         2.10.2016   2.10.2016   3.10.2016                3.10.2016

   222         3.10.2016   3.10.2016   3.10.2016    4.10.2016

   333         5.10.2016   6.10.2016   7.10.2016                 7.10.2016
```

I am creating a form named '*overview*' with two Textboxes named **StartDate** and **EndDate** and search button. What I need is When I click the search button by giving in two dates it should retrieve me the related records from the above query with all the fields in form of a report.

The **StartDate** and **EndDate** are related to the Eingang field of the query. SO when I enter 2.10.2016 as StartDate and 5.10.2016 as EndDate it must produce the above query. To achieve this I have started to create a query using the form fields which in turn can produce me the required report when I click the search button. So I am trying with the code

```
SELECT Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER,       Laufzettel.Eingang, Laufzettel.esigniert, Laufzettel.Ausgang, Laufzettel.Anlage, Laufzettel.Policierung
FROM Laufzettel
 WHERE Lauzettel.Eingang BETWEEN [Forms]![overview]![StartDate] and  [Forms]![overview]![EndDate];
```

For which I get an error *Access cannot recognise  [Forms]![overview]![StartDate] and [Forms]![overview]![EndDate] as a valid field name or expression*

How can I achieve the above? Can someone help me?

EDIT : Here is my working Query now. Although It doesn't give me the records from EndDate values.

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![overview]![start] DateTime, [Forms]![overview]![end]  DateTime;
 SELECT Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER,     Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow, Laufzettel.BEingangesigniertDokumentZWorkflow, Laufzettel.CAusgangDatenstromZWorkflow, Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL,  Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL
   FROM Laufzettel
   WHERE (((Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow) Between [Forms]! [overview]![start] And [Forms]![overview]![end]));
```

Can someone tell me where am I going Wrong?

Comment: you have a ; after from laufzettel this prematurely closes the SQL command. or was it typo?

Comment: Ah no that was a typo but its not the problem.

Comment: from where are you executing this command? post your on click procedure

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Your code behind for the "search button" so we can get the idea what is triggering the error. Your SQL looks valid unless your form name is different.

Comment: The code behind the Search button is a Run Report code which i can create when My query above works. I have a question with [Forms]![overview]![StartDate] here the StartDate is the Label Name. I have also tested with TextBox name and it still gives me the same error. But In general which name should it be

Comment: your sql looks valid, just try to create a new form. maybe your form is broken.

Comment: If the data entered into `StartDate` and `EndDate` is text, `BETWEEN` won't work; text strings aren't comparable in that way.  You'd need to change your form entry fields to gather datetime values.

Comment: I Just created a new form named Oberfla and inserted it in code * BETWEEN [Forms]![Oberfla]![StartDate] AND [Forms]![Oberfla]![EndDate]; 
* but it gives me the same error

Comment: @ashwin is the Laufzettel a standard select query? or a cross-tab? if the second you need to use proper parameters or rebuild the SQL in vba

Comment: @ Krish KM Yes the Laufzettel is a CrossTab Query. What do you mean by proper parameters? and why do I need to rebuild the code in VBA?

Comment: Can you post the code for your Laufzettel query? That would help diagnose.

Comment: @Rominus : I posted the SQL of my Laufzettel.

Comment: If you have time parts in _AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow_, use _Fix_ to remove that and leave only the date part: `Fix(Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow)`.

Comment: @ Gustav. Thanks it works. I have another problem with Datediff when i use DATEDIFF(minute,  Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL,  Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow) It gives me an error saying access does not recognize minute as field? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If build in code (VBA), try with:

```
SQL = "SELECT Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER, Laufzettel.Eingang, Laufzettel.esigniert, Laufzettel.Ausgang, Laufzettel.Anlage, Laufzettel.Policierung " & _
"FROM Laufzettel " & _
"WHERE Lauzettel.Eingang BETWEEN #" & Format([Forms]![overview]![StartDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format([Forms]![overview]![EndDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

If the "date" field really is text, apply *DateValue*:

```
SQL = "SELECT Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER, Laufzettel.Eingang, Laufzettel.esigniert, Laufzettel.Ausgang, Laufzettel.Anlage, Laufzettel.Policierung " & _
"FROM Laufzettel " & _
"WHERE DateValue(Lauzettel.Eingang) BETWEEN #" & Format([Forms]![overview]![StartDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format([Forms]![overview]![EndDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: No. That format is for display only. Assuming, of course, that the date fields are of data type Date which they must be.

Comment: @krishKM: Or, if field is text, apply _DateValue_ which converts localized text formats to date values. Se edit.

Comment: @Gustav I get a Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method when I try to execute your code by linking it to the search button